# TypedQuery giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, jpa

been doing some codes with Spring MVC and JPA and I stumbled upon this problem.

While trying to ouput one of my classes, Student in this case, I got a NullPointerException at the TypedQuery line of code

StudentDAO.java:

```
// Retrieves all the users:
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
    TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student AS s", Student.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

below is the error that appeared (EDIT: sorry was testing with another query function, changed it to the correct error message)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.prototype.spring.StudentDAO.getAllStudents(StudentDAO.java:23)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.addStudent_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.addStudent_jsp:101)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:93)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:285)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

However, when I did the exact same code with another class, CreateSession in this case, the code outputs with no errors at all. Can anyone help me understand why there are errors?

```
public List<CreateSession> getAllSessions() {
    TypedQuery<CreateSession> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM CreateSession AS s", CreateSession.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

(EDIT2: Below is the StudentDAO.java)

```
package com.prototype.spring;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class StudentDAO {
    // Injected database connection:
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

    // Stores a new User:
    @Transactional
    public void persist(Student student) {
        em.persist(student);
    }

    // Retrieves all the users:
    @Transactional
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student AS s", Student.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Student> getFromQuery(String q)
    {
            TypedQuery<Student> query = em.createQuery(q, Student.class);
            return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be your returning list is null.Check the Student has elements

Comment: mmm...the stack trace says the exception is in getFromQuery, not getAllStudents...

Comment: Iteration of students list in DAO  would return the NPE.

Comment: @Gk. I have looked into my Student table and it does have elements in it, none of the values are null

Comment: @kem sorry about that, I've changed the error message to the correct one

Comment: ok. which line is line 23? the one with em.createQuery? might be worth a quick sanity check to make sure em got initialized...

Comment: Yes line 23 is the one with em.createQuery, yea it should be initialized already, I'll add in my DAO's code into the body of the question

Comment: I would recommend verifying that the EntityManager actually got injected; em being null is the only thing I see on that line that could cause a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that `s` in your `Student` table contains a `null` value.  Since `null` is of type `Student`, it works, but you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call `getResultList()`.

Comment: I've looked into the table, but I don't see any null values inside any of the rows, would there be any other reason as to why this happened?

Comment: @qym What if what you're searching for is not in the table?  Otherwise, I have no idea.